# Como fazer operações aritméticas utilizando diretamente binário em C

Tags: c, operadores, números-binários

Sou iniciante então pode haver coisas equivocadas aqui.

Eu preciso fazer milhares de cálculos com dados (números decimais float) de vários arquivos csv gigantes, então imaginei que utilizando direto o binário no padrão ieee754 evitaria a conversão e isso economizaria tempo.

Essa foi meu teste:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a = 0b00111111110000000000000000000000; /* 1.5 */ /* uint32_t !? */
    float b = 0b00111111110000000000000000000000; /* 1.5 */  /* uint32_t !? */
    float c;

    c = a + b; /* 3.0 !? */

    printf("a: %f\n", a);
    printf("b: %f\n", b);
    printf("a+b: %f\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Ele me retorna:

```
a: 1069547520.000000
b: 1069547520.000000
a+b: 2139095040.000000
```

Eu percebi que o valor é inteiro, me parece que deveria usar `uint32_t`, ele somou os dois valores inteiros que retornou `2139095040`.

Esse valor `2139095040` que retornou me deixou confuso ele é **ieee754**? consigo converter para decimal `3.0` eu esperava retornar o binário padrão ieee754 `01000000010000000000000000000000` e assim poderia converter para decimal novamente.

Em fim, como posso utilizar dados binários ieee754 para fazer operações aritméticas e retornar o valor resultante dessa operação em binário e decimal com o objetivo de conseguir mais velocidade no processamento?

Comment: *Como fazer operações aritméticas utilizando diretamente binário em c (foi converter está errado desculpe, não consigo alterar depois de postado)

Comment: Não existe isso que está querendo fazer, pra que escrever em binário? No código é só arrumar dor de cabeça, se for um dado lido de algum lugar precisará fazer conversão e será muito mais lento. Não tente fazer algo que não conhece. Esquece isso, faça o simples e seja feliz. E espero que esse valores não sejam monetário ou que precisem de exatidão. Dê uma pesquisada aqui porque eu falo em vários lugares sobre essa maluquice que as pessoas estão colocando na cabeça que existe número binário ou não binário, existe número, só isso, o jeito que escreve não importa, use o fácil.

Comment: *não consigo alterar depois de postado* - basta clicar no link [**editar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/337866/edit) e fazer as alterações. E complementando o comentário do Maniero, números não "são" binários, eles podem ser representados de forma binária. Um número é apenas um valor. Ex: o número 3 representa apenas o valor 3 (a ideia de uma quantidade, "3 coisas"). Esse valor pode ser representado de várias formas: como o símbolo (dígito) `3`, em binário (base 2) `11`, como a palavra `três` (ou `six` em inglês, ou `三` em japonês, etc). A representação muda mas o valor é o mesmo.

Comment: @hkotsubo ok funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Se você está querendo usar a implementação nativa do compilador (e bibliotecas associadas) então não adianta querer ser mais esperto que o compilador: acredite, o pessoal que escreveu o compilador e as bibliotecas matemáticas é bastante competente. Então, a melhor coisa a fazer é não querer reinventar a roda.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double a = 1.5;
  double b = 1.5;
  double c;

  c = a + b; /* 3.0 !? */

  printf("a: %f\n", a);
  printf("b: %f\n", b);
  printf("a+b: %f\n", c);

  return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
zv@localhost Misc]$ ./so337866 
a: 1.500000
b: 1.500000
a+b: 3.000000
[zv@localhost Misc]$
```

Opcionalmente, existem bibliotecas de rotinas específicas para muitas áreas da matemática, mas normalmente só quem precisa delas são especialistas.